# wdsutil claims Windows Server 2012 R2 drivers are unsigned, but they have a valid certificate

Tags: windows-server-2012, certificate, windows-server-2012-r2, wds

I'm trying to import some Windows Server 2012 R2 drivers to a driver group in WDS. My WDS server is running Windows Server 2012 (not R2). When I run the following command:

```
WDSUTIL /Add-DriverPackage /InfFile:"E:\Drivers\Latest\WS2K12R2\ocnd64.inf" /DriverGroup:"MyDriverGroup"
```

I get this response:

```
Windows Deployment Services Management Utility [Version 6.2.9200.16384]
(C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


An error occurred while trying to execute the command.
Error Code: 0xC10301B3
Error Description: This driver package is not signed. x64-based driver packages must be signed in order to be added to the Windows Deployment Services server.
```

The folder with the driver package has a .cat file with a valid digital signature. The driver signature is recognized by a similar machine running WDS on 2012 R2. What gives? I can import Server 2012 and Server 2008 drivers just fine. Are 2012 and 2012 R2 certificates incompatible, or is something else going on?

Comment: you may serasching for this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2837108/you-cannot-import-a-windows-8-signed-driver-on-a-windows-server-2008-r Best Regards